# Frame Data accounting for distance in a fighting video game?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project that will take frame data from a fighting game, such as Street Fighter and have it predict possible combos.

However I'm not sure how to account for the distance. When an opponent is hit they are moved a certain amount. This isn't something that has a written numerical value. Any thoughts on how to handle this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .. practically, you may find the values are published, depend on the damage amount, and/or can be empirically measured!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.